# How to encapsulate common request handling in different routes in same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

In my C# MVC controller, I need to setup some object which the process of the request is required. If that object fails to setup, I need to redirect user to different link.

My question is I need to do that in every route of my controller, how can I do that without copy and paste code?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Route1()
{
    var setupObject = InitSetup();
    if (setupObject == null)
         return Redirect();

    if (some check fail)
         return Redirect();

    //process Route1 request which needs setupObject  not null;
    return Ok();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Route2()
{
    var setupObject = InitSetup();
    if (setupObject == null)
         return Redirect();

    if (some check fail)
         return Redirect();

    //process Route2 request which needs setupObject  not null;
    return Ok();
}
```

I would like to know how i can not copy and paste this

```
    var setupObject = InitSetup();
    if (setupObject == null)
         return Redirect();

    if (some check fail)
         return Redirect();
```

Comment: Create a custom `FilterAttribute` and apply it to the controller (or to action methods in the controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute some code prior to executing every action in your controller then you can override the OnActionExecuting method in your controller or in your base controller (if you have any)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx